# SwiftUI Form Layout Bug with Animation

Tags: forms, animation, swiftui

I have read similar descriptions about this issue but none are exactly this and the work-arounds do not seem applicable to me. I would like to know if anyone else has experienced this, if there is a way to use animation to display a Form, or if this is worth reporting as a bug to Apple.

I have `ContentView` with a couple of buttons which toggle a boolean. One button simply toggles the boolean while the other toggles the boolean within an animation block. The boolean controls which of two Form views are displayed. When toggled *without* the animation the Forms render correctly. But when toggled within the animation block, the Forms are rendered incorrectly.

This is the "Normal" (aka `ReviewSheet`) view.

[image: The ContentView showing the ReviewSheet]

When you tap "Edit" it switches to the `BugSheet` view. Looks fine.

[image: BugSheet displayed without animation]

If you pick the "Bug It" button this is how `BugSheet` is rendered:

[image: BugSheet displayed with animation]

The Form in `BugSheet` is now rendered with the first section's `header` overlapping an enlarged content area and in the second section, the `Text` is no longer rendered onto multiple lines (using `lineLimit` modifier has no effect).

Here is the code for each of these three views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Text("Form Bug")
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
                
                // This "Edit" button just toggles isEditing and doing this
                // the switch between BugSheet and ReviewSheet appears as you
                // would expect.
                Button(isEditing ? "Save 1" : "Edit") {
                    isEditing.toggle()
                }
                
                // This "Edit" button also toggle isEditing but does so within
                // an animation block. The switch between BugSheet and ReviewSheet
                // leaves the Form rendered improperly.
                Button(isEditing ? "Save 2" :
                        "Bug It") {
                    withAnimation {
                        isEditing.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            if isEditing {
                BugSheet()
            } else {
                ReviewSheet()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReviewSheet: View {
    @State private var titleText: String = "Example Title"
    @State private var shortDescription: String = "This should work"
    @State private var keywords: String = "swiftui, apple, form, bug"
    
    let longDescription = "The rain in Spain stays mainly on the Plains even while the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Title")) {
                Text(titleText)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                Text(shortDescription)
                Text(longDescription)
                Text(keywords)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BugSheet: View {
    
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case title
        case shorty
        case keywords
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    @State private var titleText: String = ""
    @State private var shortDescription: String = ""
    @State private var keywords: String = ""
    @State private var notes: String = "This is a starter note."
    
    let longDescription = "The rain in Spain stays mainly on the Plains even while the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    
    private func gotoField(_ field: Field) {
        focusedField = field
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Title")) {
                TextField("title here", text: $titleText, onCommit: {gotoField(.shorty)})
                    .autocapitalization(.words)
                    .disableAutocorrection(false)
                    .keyboardType(.default)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .title)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                TextField("short description", text: $shortDescription, onCommit: {gotoField(.keywords)})
                    .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                    .disableAutocorrection(false)
                    .keyboardType(.default)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .shorty)
                Text(longDescription)
                TextField("keywords", text: $keywords, onCommit: {gotoField(.title)})
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .keyboardType(.default)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .keywords)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is SwiftUI 3, it is also reproducible with Swift UI 2.